# Problem with a custom drawn list view

Tags: c++, winapi

I created a list view class that uses Custom Draw for its rendering. It all works well except that it doesn't render anything. I subclassed its parent window to catch the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` notification as a `WM_NOTIFY` message. However, it appears that `WM_NOTIFY` is only triggered a few times during creation of the control and never again after that. So the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` code is never executed.

I checked with Winspector Spy so see if the control is laid out correctly in the parent window and that seems to be fine.

Does anyone have a clue about what I may be doing wrong?

The code can be found online:

- [WindowsListView.h](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/include/XULWin/WindowsListView.h)
- [WindowsListView.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/src/WindowsListView.cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call `ShowWindow(mHandle, SW_SHOW);` after creating the list view.

Doh!

Comment: That'll do it.  Or use `WS_VISIBLE`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you drawing text in CDDS_ITEMPOSTPAINT? You should probably draw your text in CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT and return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT. Also, you should not use the rect in NMCUSTOMDRAW, call ListView_GetItemRect to get the rect you are really after (LVIR_LABEL for text etc)

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that. But the problem is that I don't receive the NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification at all.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're using the [`LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774739.aspx) style, which could explain why you don't get owner-draw messages.

Comment: I believe owner draw is a separate concept from custom draw. Anyway I tried setting the flag and I still don't get the NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification.